# how to invoke cmd command from WCF library C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a C# WCF library and I want to invoke the cmd command from one of the method in WCF library, but when I run the code and call that method, it neither executes cmd command nor generates any kind of exception, what should I do, my code is as under..please someone guide me.

I have already verified the command on cmd, it executes successfully from the cmd  , but not from the WCF library, so there is no any problem in command syntax.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo Info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
Info.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Info.Arguments= 
         "\"" + tallyPath + "\"" + "  " 
         + "/TDL:" + tdlPath + " " + "/LOAD:" 
         + cmpCode + "  " + "/SETVAR:SVVarUN:" 
         + uname + " " + "/SETVAR:SVVarPass:"
         + pwd;

proc.StartInfo = startInfo
proc.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer - I have built the simplest of WCF services to try and mimic your scenario as best as possible. I have tested this and it works fine (pasted below). Pay attention to the commented out lines that didn't seem to look right in your example above. You also had an issue with your StartInfo - you create is as "Info" but set "proc.StartInfo = startInfo" which does not seem to exist - it should be set to just "Info".

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string RunTally();
    }

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string RunTally()
        {
            var tallyPath = "C:\\temp\\";
            var tallyExe = "tally.exe";
            var cmpCode = "myCmpCode";
            var uname = "myUname";
            var pwd = "myPwd";
            var tdlPath = "myTdlPath";

            Process proc = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardError = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.Arguments =
                // "\"" + tallyPath + "\"" + "  "
                 // +
                 "/TDL:" + tdlPath + " " + "/LOAD:"
                 + cmpCode + "  " + "/SETVAR:SVVarUN:"
                 + uname + " " + "/SETVAR:SVVarPass:"
                 + pwd;
            info.FileName = tallyPath + tallyExe;

            proc.StartInfo = info;            
            proc.Start();

            var textReceived = "";
            while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                textReceived += proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            }

            return string.Format("The call returned: " + textReceived);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what should I write in place of  "program.exe", I want to execute the cmd command ,so what else should I write,there is no other executable is needed.

Comment: cmd just gives you a command window. What would you run after that?

Comment: Ok..I have put Tally.exe on that place but still it is not working...is there any problem related to GUI support with WCF library..??

Comment: There should not be an issue. Does Tally.exe output to the console? Have you set the additional items as per the below answer?   process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

Comment: And does Tally require elevated privileges? And what exitcode does it give to proc?

Comment: actually I need to execute the cmd command from C# code to open the tally.exe...and yes I have done all the settings correctly as said by you, and cmd command will be input(i.e username and password) to the tally.exe to perform the login externally.sorry if any misunderstandings...

Comment: No Tally doesn't require elevated previllages, when I execute the command as shown in my code, from the cmd console directly then it shows exit code 3, however it executes successfully from the cmd console.

Comment: I did appropriate changes in code,the code runs without any problem, but its not opening Tally...I think problem is security or permission related.. as Avneesh said: "The security permission sometimes block the command line exe and asking for confirmation dialog, which is not visible"..I guess so..

Comment: Indeed, or your arguments and/or path are not properly formatted.

Comment: Cool. Let me know whats missing and you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on some of the servers and it was due to 2 issues 
1. The security permission sometimes block the command line exe and asking for confirmation dialog, which is not visible.
2. Another issue is solved using the following settings:

```
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
```